# NHibernate.MappingException: No persister No mapped documents found in assembly

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have been doing nhibernate since many days. But Today I stuck at a frustrating issue i.e. mapping exception.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="IPC.Base.Domains" assembly="IPC">
  <class name="MenuItem" table="dbo.COR_MenuItem" default-access="property" default-cascade="save-update" default-lazy="true">
    <cache usage="read-only" region="completelyStatic"/>
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="System.String" />
    <property name="Order" column="DisplayOrder" />
    <property name="Key" column="KeyChain" />
    <property name="Route" />
    <property name="ActionMethod" />
    <property name="IsHotlink" />
    <many-to-one name="ParentMenuItem" column="ParentMenuItemId" class="MenuItem" cascade="none"/>
    <bag name="MenuItems" table="dbo.COR_MenuItem" cascade="none">
      <cache usage="read-only" region="completelyStatic"/>
      <key column="ParentMenuItemId" />
      <one-to-many class="MenuItem" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And I do have a mapping class as following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IPC.Base.Domain
{
    public partial class MenuItem : PersistentObject
    {
        public MenuItem()
        {
            MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
        }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int? Order { get; set; }
        public virtual string Key { get; set; }
        public virtual string Route { get; set; }
        public virtual string ActionMethod { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsHotlink { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
        public virtual MenuItem ParentMenuItem { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// only to be used from the menu builder app
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        public virtual void SetId(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following nHibernate Config running with the application. But as per my experience there is absolutely no issue with the nHibernate Config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
 <session-factory name="IPC">
  <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">**************SQL CONNECTION****************/property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache</property>
  <property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping assembly="IPC"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am using the following line for code for invoking nHibernate session object to system.

```
static ISessionFactory CurrentFactory
        {
            get
            {
                if (factory == null)
                {
                    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
                    if (cfgFile == null)
                        cfg = cfg.Configure();
                    else
                        cfg = cfg.Configure(cfgFile);

                    factory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
                }
                return factory;
            }
        }
        public static ISession Create()
        {
            var session = CurrentFactory.OpenSession();
            return session;
        }
```

Now! When I call the following line of code I am getting:

```
public virtual T Get(int id)
        {
            return Session.Get<T>(id);
        }


No persister for: IPC.Base.Domain.MenuItem
Exception Details: NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for: IPC.Base.Domain.MenuItem
```

I have already enabled by nHibernate log. Following are the basic details from log

```
00:54:40.011 [4] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment - NHibernate 2.1.0.4000 (2.1.0.4000)
00:54:40.055 [4] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : lcg
00:54:40.057 [4] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment - Using reflection optimizer
00:54:40.682 [4] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - dialect=NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect
00:54:40.683 [4] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - connection.driver_class=NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
00:54:40.683 [4] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - connection.connection_string=*********************SQL Connection*****************
00:54:40.683 [4] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - proxyfactory.factory_class=NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu
00:54:40.683 [4] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - cache.provider_class=NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache
00:54:40.683 [4] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - cache.use_query_cache=true
00:54:40.683 [4] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - show_sql=true
00:54:40.684 [4] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - IPC<-IPC
00:54:40.685 [4] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - Searching for mapped documents in assembly: IPC
00:54:40.689 [4] WARN  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - No mapped documents found in assembly: IPC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
00:54:40.691 [4] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: IPC
00:54:40.691 [4] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - properties: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]
00:54:45.716 [4] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - checking mappings queue
00:54:45.716 [4] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - processing one-to-many association mappings
00:54:45.717 [4] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - processing one-to-one association property references
00:54:45.717 [4] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - processing foreign key constraints
00:54:45.747 [4] INFO  NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect
```

I have read almost all the post with stack! :) and even doing google for the same. The final words I am getting there is an issue with my assembly naming! I sure that there is a issue with the steps which I have followed. But still searching for that trigger!!!

Thanks! 
In advance!!

Answer (score 11):

Probably you forgot to set your hbm mappings as embedded resource to the DLL.

Comment: Would be nice to describe how its fixed - similar to how the OP answered his own question except that answer is still missing the actual steps - ie, Build Action -> Embedded Resource

Answer (score 4):

Finally I resolved the issue! Its basically a stupid stuff which normally I tend to do and then forget to get it back on running stage.

Yes, I was related with the assembly issue. Nothing but when I was trying to build then data layer application It was not enbading the xml files inside assembly.

> A Fix for solve the problem go to your
>   *.hbm.xml files and do a right click and change build option of that file
>   to embedded resource.

Alrite!

Many thanks!